Problemas con los servicios de WampServer 32bits
tengo un problema con wampserver de 32 bits, cuando el programa se inicia y termina de iniciar todos los servicios, siempre el icono de wampserver queda de color naranja diciendo que 2 de 3 servicios se están ejecutando.
Al hacer la comprobación de estado de los servicios, obtengo los siguientes resultados:

Ya intente solucionar el problema cambiando los puertos de cada servicio, pero sigo recibiendo el mismo error. Por cierto actualmente todos los servicios tienen la configuración por defecto

Verifica las dependencias. PHP para windows requiere vcredist, asegúrate de tener instalados vcredist (2012, 1013, 2015-2022) tanto para 32 bits como 64 bits (si el equipo es x64), en la página de Wampp hay un botón para descargarlas (VC++ Packages). Si eso ya está, instalar y también iniciar Wamp siempre con "Ejecutar como administrador".
